# How to pass textbox value to bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell, cgi

This is my first question, CMIIW :

here my sample php script

```
<form method="GET" action="/var/www/cgi-bin/mode2.sh">
     <table align="center" nowrap>
<tr>><td>IP address :</TD><TD><input type="text" name="ip"></td></tr>
<tr><td>netmask :</TD><TD><input type="text" name="ip2"></td></tr>
</tr></table>

 <input type="submit" value="Send">
 <input type="reset" value="Reset"></p></form>
```

bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo "IPADDR=$ip"       >>/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
echo "NETMASK=$ip2"     >>/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

I want input textbox value form web browser for example IP and netmask and send the value to bash and save to ifcfg-eth0 file. i know it sound risky, i just want to learn. any sugestion?

Comment: This is not going to work like this, at the very least you need to set the `action` attibute to a path that is accessible by the web-server, in your case probably: `/cgi-bin/mode2.sh`. Then the web-server will probably just show you `mode2.sh` as a text file, unless you have some special configuration that will allow the web-server to execute shell scripts.

Comment: my sample php, i cut my script.any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having action attribute point to shell script you want to run, Make action attribute to point to php file like

```
<form method="GET" action="UserInputIPAddrPHP.php">
```

And in the UserInputIPAddrPHP.php you can get the User Inputted IP and Netmask as follows

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$IP_Addr = $_GET['ip'];
$NetMask = $_GET['ip2'];
$command="/path/to/mode2.sh ".escapeshellarg($IP_Addr)." ".escapeshellarg($NetMask);
exec ($command,$output=array(),$return_value);
if($return_value!==0) {
    #print appropriate message
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

$command is actual command that you type to run the script at your shell. So set it accordingly.

Write your script mode2.sh like this (mind the quotes):

```
#!/bin/sh
command "$1" "$2"; # command is actual command you want to run like cp,mv etc
```

Render it executable:

```
me@somewhere$ chmod +x mode2.sh
```

Hope this might help you

Thanks

Comment: i have tried to follow your step, still cant send the value to bash.
UserInputIPAddrPHP.php sript :
`$sh="/path/to/mode2.sh ".escapeshellarg($IP_Addr)." ".escapeshellarg($NetMask);
exec ($sh,$output=array(),$return_value);`

bash script :
`echo =echo "IPADDR=$1"       >>/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
echo "NETMASK=$2"     >>/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

Comment: @Haruru Please find the below script to redirect the user input(IP,NetMask) to file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 IP="$1";
NetMask="$2";
echo "$IP" >>/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
echo "$NetMask" >>/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 Hope this might help you Thanks

Comment: Also try to print the values of variables before sending to bash scripts i.e print $IP and $Netmask

Comment: @Haruru Alwys Welcome. Any help please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You should not use bash as cgi script.
But if there is really a need, you can get IP and netmask by manipulating variable `$QUERY_STRING`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type:text/plain
echo ""

read IP MASK <<< $(echo $QUERY_STRING |  sed -r 's/&?ip2?=/ /g')
```